# How can I use current query value in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new with sequelize and i need to include multiple table, i try belove:

```
const result = await product.findAll({
        where: {
            isDeleted: false,
            sellerId
        },
        attributes: ["name", "type", "isActive", "subCategoryIds"],
        include: [
            {
                model: category,
                as: 'categories',
                attributes: ["name"],
            },
            {
                model: category,
                as: 'subCategories',
                attributes: ["name"],
                where: {
                    id: _.split(sequelize.col("subCategoryIds"), ",")
                },
            },
        ],
        offset: (page - 1) * limit,
        limit
    });
```

But it's return error :

> SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Product model is:

```
const product = sequelize.define("products",
{
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
      field: "id",
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      index: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "name",
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "type",
      allowNull: false,
    },
    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      field: "categoryId",
      references: {
        key: "id",
        model: category,
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    sellerId: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      field: "sellerId",
      references: {
        key: "id",
        model: user,
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    subCategoryIds: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      get() {
        const result = _.split(this.getDataValue("subCategoryIds"), ",").map(item => +item);
        return result;
      }
    },
    isDeleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      field: "isDeleted",
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      field: "createdAt",
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      field: "updatedAt",
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    }
  }, {
  tableName: "products",
  timestamps: false
}
);

product.belongsTo(category, { as: "categories", foreignKey: 'categoryId' });
category.hasMany(product, { as: "products", foreignKey: 'categoryId' });

product.belongsTo(category, { as: "subCategories", foreignKey: 'subCategoryIds' });
```

I am not getting what's going wrong
is there any solution for this

details in table like

> categoryId => 11 subCategoryIds => 11, 12

if i remove

```
       {
            model: category,
            as: 'subCategories',
            attributes: ["name"],
            where: {
                id: _.split(sequelize.col("subCategoryIds"), ",")
            },
        },
```

then it's working fine, problem is sequelize.col("subCategoryIds") return string col("subCategoryIds") not the actual value of the subCategories ids 11, 12

Comment: Please check to make sure that you are using the same data types in your queries as defined in your schema, i.e. make sure you compare an integer with an integer and not with say a varchar/string.

Comment: @JonasTomanga I got your point, it's also clear in error but I am not know how can I do this.

Comment: Check if sellerId is a number, if not convert it to a number, i.e with `parseInt(sellerId)`

Comment: @JonasTomanga probleme is with sequelize.col("subCategoryIds") it's return col("subCategoryIds") not the actual value of subcategories.